# working with relative paths in powershell WebClient and FileStream

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm tasked with writing a powershell script to perform a file download, which will eventually be executed as a scheduled task once a week. I have no background in programming in the windows environment so this has been an interesting day.

I am experiencing a problem with the unexpected handling of the `$pwd` and `$home` of the shell.

I pass into my program a download URL and a destination file. I would like the destination file to be a relative path, e.g., `download/temp.txt.gz`

```
param($srcUrl, $destFile)

$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($srcUrl, $destFile)

Ungzip-File $destFile

Remove-Item $destFile
```

This actually fails on the call to `Remove-Item`. If `$destFile` is a relative path then the script happily downloads the file and puts it in a file relative to `$home`. Likewise, I then unzip this and my function `Ungzip-File` makes use of `System.IO.Filestream`, and it seems to find this file. Then `Remove-Item` complains that there is no file in the path relative to `$pwd`.

I am a bit baffled, as these are all part of the shell, so to speak. I'm not clear why these functions would handle the path differently and, more to the point, I'm not sure how to fix this so both relative and absolute paths work. I've tried looking at the `io.path` methods but since my `$home` and `$pwd` are on different drives, I can't even use the `IsPathRooted` which was seemed so close when I found it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware of where you are in the path. $pwd works just fine on the command shell but let's say you have started your script from a scheduled job. You might think $pwd is where your script resides and code accordingly but find out that it actually uses, say %windir%\system32.

In general, I would use fullpath to destination and for paths relative to script folder I would use $PSScriptRoot/folder_name/file_path.

There are catches there too. For example, I noticed $PSScriptRoot will resolve just fine within the script but not within Param() block. I would highly suggest using write-verbose when coding and testing, so you know what it thinks the path is.

```
[CMDLETBINDING()] ## you need this!
Param()
write-verbose "path is $pwd"
Write-Verbose "removing $destFile"
Remove-Item $destfile
```

and add -verbose when you are calling your script/function:

```
myscript.ps1 -verbose
mydownloadfunction -verbose
```

Comment: No, it's not an issue of not knowing where you are. I know where I am - some commands just ignore it and choose to interpret relative paths based on your the location of your script instead.

Answer (score 1):

To use a relative path, you need to specify the current directory with `./`

Example: `./download/temp.txt.gz`

You can also change your location in the middle of the script with `Set-Location` (alias: `cd`)

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried to do, thinking it was trying to resolve the path from the root. The problem is that the relative path is different for these "microsoft" calls. I would expect the methods to use $home or $pwd, but not "sometimes one, sometimes the other."

Comment: Most of the time it is relative to the script itself or wherever the script is "started in"